# Login security concern with cookie in PHP

Tags: php, security, authentication, session-cookies

I'm building an application in PHP with a private access. There are two ways to log in:

- Login form: username and password
- Cookie: remembered cookie with hashed information (username, salt, etc.)

To prevent robots doing a brute force attack, the server creates a session (a cookie with session_start), after 4 attempts, the user has to wait 5 seconds before trying again. I'm using the superglobal variable $_SESSION to check how many times someone tries to connect.

My concern is about users that don't allow cookies. In that case, they won't have to wait 5 seconds every 4 attempts. I'm a bit confused regarding the best way to prevent brute force:

1. Creating a login table in the database that checks how many times an IP tries to connect
2. Or simply preventing users without session cookie from connecting

Thanks,

Comment: Your #2 won't work, since *everyone* will have *no session cookie* on the first login attempt. The only solution for throttling attempts is by tracking each IP; cookies simply don't have any role to play in this scenario.

Comment: Storing login attempts in the session is rather pointless – because I only need to get a new session to start over again. (And “getting a new session” would basically just require to send a different random session id.) You should rather store that info on the user object (in your database).

Comment: OK thanks, I think everyone will have a session cookie on the first attempt because it's created at the beginning of the checkLogin script. Indeed a php session just requires to send a random session, didn't think about this. Store info in the db looks good. Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I'd definately go for the db based solution. Maybe lock the account for 2 minutes after 5 failed attempts but this is really just a personal decision.. However, you might not wanna block the IPs since a lot of big companies and even countries communicate using one NATted IP, instead I'd lock the account.

Comment: You mention to block THE account, but what account is to be blocked since the account name is filled in by brute force? Or you want to block all multiple entered account names and flood you db?

Answer (score -2):

You can take a look at
http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/throttle-user-login-attempts-in-php/
and judge for yourself.

Comment: thanks for the link, I had a look, and it seems exactly what I need.

Comment: Your Welcome @Yoan . Too bad it gets Down Votes. Probably because the code is old and PDO and such should be used, but it was meant to be about giving you an idea about throttling login attempts. BTW: I've found this link here on Stack Overflow in an UP voted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17912394/2151104